# SIGBUS occurs when fortran code reads file on linux cluster

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi, sigbus

When I run my fortran code in parallel on a linux cluster with mpirun I get a sigbus error.
It occurs while reading a file, the timing is irregular, and sometimes it proceeds without error.
I have tried debug compilation options like -g, but I haven't gotten any information on what line the error is coming from.
Actually the code was executed previously in three different clusters without this error, but the error is only occurring on this machine.
I personally suspect this is related to the performance of the machine (especially storage i/o), but I am not sure.

The program code is simple. Each process executed by mpirun reads the file corresponding to its rank as follows.

```
!!!!!!!!!! start of code
OPEN(11, FILE='FILE_NAME_WITH_RANK', FORM='UNFORMATTED')
READ(11,*) ISIZE
ALLOCATE(SOME_VARIABLE(ISIZE))
DO I = 1, ISIZE
READ(11,*) SOME_VARIABLE(I)
ENDDO
READ(11,*) ISIZE2
ALLOCATE(SOME_VARIABLE2(ISIZE2))
DO I = 1, ISIZE2
READ(11,*) SOME_VARIABLE2(I)
ENDDO
! MORE VARIABLES
CLOSE(11)
!!!!!!!!!! end of code
```

I used 191 cpu, and the total size of 191 files it loads is about 11 GB.

The cluster used for execution consists of 24 nodes with 16 cpu each (384 cpu total) and uses common storage that is shared with another cluster.
I ran the code in parallel by specifying nodes 1 through 12 as the hostfile.

Initially, I had 191 cpu read all files at the same time out of sequence.
After doing so, the program ended with a sigbus error. Also, for some nodes, the ssh connection was delayed, and the bashrc file cannot be found by node with stale file handle error.
The stale file handle error waited a bit and it seemed to recover by itself, but I'm not sure what the system administrator did.
So, I changed it to the following code so that only one cpu can read the file at a time.

```
!!!!!!!!!! start of code
DO ICPU = 0, NUMBER_OF_PROCESS-1
IF(ICPU.EQ.MY_PROCESS) CALL READ_FILE
CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMMUNICATOR,IERR)
ENDDO
!!!!!!!!!! end of code
```

This seemed to work fine for single execution, but if I ran more than one of these programs at the same time, the first mpirun stopped and both ended with a sigbus error eventually.

My next attempt is to minimize the execution of the read statement by deleting the do statement when reading the array. However, due to limited time, I couldn't test the effectiveness of this modification.

Here are some additional information.

- If I execute a search or copy a file with an explorer such as nautilus while running a parallel program, nautilus does not respond or the running program raise sigbus. In severe cases, I wasn't able to connect the VNC server with stale file handle errors.
- I use OpenMPI 2.1.1, GNU Fortran 4.9.4.
  I compile the program with following
  $OPENMPIHOME/bin/mpif90 -mcmodel=large -fmax-stack-var-size-64 -cpp -O3 $SOURCE -o $EXE
  I execute the program with following in gnome terminal
  $OPENMPIHOME/bin/mpirun -np $NP -x $LD_LIBRARY_PATH --hostfile $HOSTFILE $EXE
- The cluster is said to be running commercial software like FLUENT without problems.

Summing up the above, my personal suspicion is that the storage of the cluster is dismounted due to the excessive disk I/O generated by my code, but I don't know if this makes sense because I have no cluster knowledge.
If yes, I wonder if there is a way to minimize the disk I/O, if it is enough to proceed with the vectorized I/O mentioned above, or if there is an additional part.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me anything about the problem.
Thanks in advance.

!!!
I wrote an example code. As mentioned above, it may not be easy to reproduce because the occurrence varies depending on the machine.

```
    PROGRAM BUSWRITE
    
    IMPLICIT NONE
    
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ISIZE1 = 10000, ISIZE2 = 20000, ISIZE3 = 30000
    DOUBLE PRECISION, ALLOCATABLE :: ARRAY1(:), ARRAY2(:), ARRAY3(:)
    INTEGER :: I
    INTEGER :: I1, I2, I3
    CHARACTER*3 CPUNUM
    
    INCLUDE 'mpif.h'
    INTEGER ISTATUS(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
    INTEGER :: IERR, NPES, MYPE
    
    CALL MPI_INIT(IERR)
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,NPES,IERR)
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,MYPE,IERR)
    
    I1=MOD(MYPE/100,10)+48
    I2=MOD(MYPE/10 ,10)+48
    I3=MOD(MYPE    ,10)+48
    CPUNUM=CHAR(I1)//CHAR(I2)//CHAR(I3)
    
    OPEN(11, FILE=CPUNUM//'.DAT', FORM='UNFORMATTED')
    ALLOCATE(ARRAY1(ISIZE1))
    ALLOCATE(ARRAY2(ISIZE2))
    ALLOCATE(ARRAY3(ISIZE3))
    DO I = 1, ISIZE1
    ARRAY1(I) = I
    WRITE(11) ARRAY1(I)
    ENDDO
    DO I = 1, ISIZE2
    ARRAY2(I) = I**2
    WRITE(11) ARRAY2(I)
    ENDDO
    DO I = 1, ISIZE3
    ARRAY3(I) = I**3
    WRITE(11) ARRAY3(I)
    ENDDO
    CLOSE(11)
    
    CALL MPI_FINALIZE(IERR)
    END PROGRAM
```

```
mpif90 -ffree-line-length-0 ./buswrite.f90 -o ./buswrite
mpirun -np 32 ./buswrite
```

I've got 32 000.DAT ~ 031.DAT

```
    PROGRAM BUSREAD
    
    IMPLICIT NONE
    
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: ISIZE1 = 10000, ISIZE2 = 20000, ISIZE3 = 30000
    DOUBLE PRECISION, ALLOCATABLE :: ARRAY1(:), ARRAY2(:), ARRAY3(:)
    INTEGER :: I
    INTEGER :: I1, I2, I3
    CHARACTER*3 CPUNUM
    
    INCLUDE 'mpif.h'
    INTEGER ISTATUS(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
    INTEGER :: IERR, NPES, MYPE
    
    CALL MPI_INIT(IERR)
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,NPES,IERR)
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,MYPE,IERR)
    
    I1=MOD(MYPE/100,10)+48
    I2=MOD(MYPE/10 ,10)+48
    I3=MOD(MYPE    ,10)+48
    CPUNUM=CHAR(I1)//CHAR(I2)//CHAR(I3)
    
    OPEN(11, FILE=CPUNUM//'.DAT', FORM='UNFORMATTED')
    ALLOCATE(ARRAY1(ISIZE1))
    ALLOCATE(ARRAY2(ISIZE2))
    ALLOCATE(ARRAY3(ISIZE3))
    DO I = 1, ISIZE1
    READ(11) ARRAY1(I)
    IF(ARRAY1(I).NE.I) STOP
    ENDDO
    DO I = 1, ISIZE2
    READ(11) ARRAY2(I)
    IF(ARRAY2(I).NE.I**2) STOP
    ENDDO
    DO I = 1, ISIZE3
    READ(11) ARRAY3(I)
    IF(ARRAY3(I).NE.I**3) STOP
    ENDDO
    CLOSE(11)
    
    CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
    IF(MYPE.EQ.0) WRITE(*,*) 'GOOD'
    CALL MPI_FINALIZE(IERR)
    END PROGRAM
```

```
mpif90 -ffree-line-length-0 ./busread.f90 -o ./busread
mpirun -np 32 ./busread
```

I've got 'GOOD' output text from terminal as expected, but the machine in question is terminated with a sigbus error while running busread.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] around the site. How many processes are there in one node? Do all processes in one node read all a single file? If fear we really need more code and a specific example, see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Have you run your pogram with all the run time checking options turned on (It maybe -fcheck=all , but that is an ancient version of gfortran so I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: Thanks for comments. Each node had 16 threads, so I used 16 processes per node. Each process reads each file specified for the process number, not the node number. I incorrectly wrote the node number in the text, but fixed it with the process number. Sorry for the confusion.I thought of attaching the actual code, but the content was so vast that I tried to write only the relevant part as an example. As mentioned above, this error may or may not occur depending on the machine, so I am not sure if it will help. Also, please tell me if there is anything I should provide.

Comment: For the compile options I used the following options. -fbounds-check -fbacktrace . I'm willing to test it out with other options, but I think it won't be possible right away due to facility access issues.

Comment: Irrelevant comment: to transform an integer into a 3-character string, with leading 0s, you could write `write(cpunum,'(i3.3)') mype`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not observed after a device reboot. Even though I ran 4 programs at the same time under the same conditions, no problem occurred. In addition, other teams that used the device also had similar problems, which were resolved after reboot. The conclusion is a bit ridiculous, but if there are any people experiencing similar problems, I would like to summarize it as follows.

If your program terminates abnormally due to a memory error (like sigbus and sigsegv) while reading or writing a file, you can check the following.

- Make sure there are no errors in your program. Check whether the time of occurrence of the error is constant or irregular, whether other programs have the same symptoms, whether it runs well on other machines, and whether there is a problem when run with a memory error checking tool such as valgrind.
- Optimize the file I/O part. In the case of fortran, processing an entire array is tens of times faster than processing by element.
- Immediately after an error occurs, try ssh connection to the machine (or node) to check whether the connection is smooth and that the file system is well accessed. If you cannot access the bashrc file or an error such as stale file handle occurs, please contact the system manager after combining the above reviewed information.

If someone has anything to add or if this post isn't appropriate, please let me know.